# running a command line containing Pipes and displaying result to STDOUT

Tags: python, command-line, pipe

How would one call a shell command from Python which contains a pipe and capture the output?

Suppose the command was something like:

```
cat file.log | tail -1
```

The Perl equivalent of what I am trying to do would be something like:

```
my $string = `cat file.log | tail -1`;
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Use a subprocess.PIPE, as explained in the subprocess docs section ["Replacing shell pipeline"](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline):

```
import subprocess
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["cat", "file.log"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["tail", "-1"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
output,err = p2.communicate()
```

Or, using the [`sh` module](https://github.com/amoffat/sh), piping becomes [composition of functions](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/#piping):

```
import sh
output = sh.tail(sh.cat('file.log'), '-1')
```

Comment: Wow. So much more concise than the Perl way.

Answer (score 8):

This:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("cat file.log | tail -1", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
#for shell=False use absolute paths
p_stdout = p.stdout.read()
p_stderr = p.stderr.read()
print p_stdout
```

---

Or this should work:

```
import os
result = os.system("cat file.log | tail -1")
```

Comment: I can get the second solution to work. Trying the first solution with Python 2.6.7, I get an error raised on the Popen line and error printed is "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory". Unclear why this is happening.

Comment: Try using the absolute path of `file.log`. Or, try `shell=True`.

Comment: `shell=False` should be `shell=True`

Comment: Setting shell=True fixed it. Thx!

Comment: I need to write something like subprocess.Popen("ps aux | grep php | wc -l", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
The answer solve my problem. thanks

Comment: `os.system` returns the exit code, not the stdout

Answer (score 8):

```
import subprocess
task = subprocess.Popen("cat file.log | tail -1", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
data = task.stdout.read()
assert task.wait() == 0
```

Note that this does not capture stderr.  And if you want to capture stderr as well, you'll need to use `task.communicate()`; calling `task.stdout.read()` and then `task.stderr.read()` can deadlock if the buffer for stderr fills.   If you want them combined, you should be able to use `2>&1` as part of the shell command.

But given your exact case,

```
task = subprocess.Popen(['tail', '-1', 'file.log'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
data = task.stdout.read()
assert task.wait() == 0
```

avoids the need for the pipe at all.

Answer (score 4):

Another way similar to Popen would be:

```
command=r"""cat file.log | tail -1 """
output=subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a fork from **@chown** with some improvements:

- an alias for `import subprocess`, makes easier when setting parameters
- if you just want the output, you don't need to set `stderr` or `stdin` when calling `Popen`
- for better formatting, it's recommended to decode the output
- `shell=True` is necessary, in order to call an interpreter for the command line

---

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess as sp

p = sp.Popen("cat app.log | grep guido", shell=True, stdout=sp.PIPE)

output = p.stdout.read()
print(output.decode('utf-8'))
```

---

```
$ cat app.log 
2017-10-14 22:34:12, User Removed [albert.wesker]
2017-10-26 18:14:02, User Removed [alexei.ivanovich] 
2017-10-28 12:14:56, User Created [ivan.leon]
2017-11-14 09:22:07, User Created [guido.rossum]

$ python3 subproc.py 
2017-11-14 09:22:07, User Created [guido.rossum]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple function for run shell command with many pipes

**Using**

```
res, err = eval_shell_cmd('pacman -Qii | grep MODIFIED | grep -v UN | cut -f 2')
```

**Function**

```
import subprocess


def eval_shell_cmd(command, debug=False):
    """
    Eval shell command with pipes and return result
    :param command: Shell command
    :param debug: Debug flag
    :return: Result string
    """
    processes = command.split(' | ')

    if debug:
        print('Processes:', processes)

    for index, value in enumerate(processes):
        args = value.split(' ')

        if debug:
            print(index, args)

        if index == 0:
            p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        else:
            p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=p.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

        if index == len(processes) - 1:
            result, error = p.communicate()
            return result.decode('utf-8'), error
```