# how to call xargs using script

Tags: python, xargs, file-copying

I am new to python and still at the level of basic learning. Recently I tried to write a script to generate new folders according to the number supplied in the input text file. After creating those folders I want to copy a file into all those folders at the same time. I can do it by typing

```
echo equil{1..x} | xargs -n 1 cp *.txt *
```

in the terminal, and it works fine. Here x is the number of folders I have in my working directory. But my concern is to make it automatic, i.e. to call it from the script, so that the user doesn't need to type this line every time in the terminal. That is why I tried this

```
sub2 = subprocess.call(['echo', 'equil{1..x}', '|', 'xargs', '-n', '1', 'cp', '*.txt *'])
```

Can anyone please guide me and show me the mistake. Actually I am not getting any error, rather it is printing this

```
equil{1..x} | xargs -n 1 cp *.txt *
```

in the terminal after executing the rest of the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `subprocess.Popen` if you want to send data to/from stdin/stdout of your subprocesses. And you have to `Popen` a subprocess for each of the executables, i.e. in your example, one for `echo` and one for `xargs`.

There is an example in the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline

Another here: [Call a shell command containing a 'pipe' from Python and capture STDOUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353054/call-a-shell-command-containing-a-pipe-from-python-and-capture-stdout)

However, instead of running `echo` to produce some lines, you can directly write them in python to the process *stdin*.

Comment: Actually I just want to copy a single file into several folders at the same time using script.

Comment: Well, wouldn't it be easier to do it in Python? A bit of useful functions: [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir), [`os.makedirs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs), [`shutil.copyfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile), [`for`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use subprocess.call() like this with pipes. For recipes how to use pipes, see

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline

I.e. you would use subprocess.communicate() over two processes.

Comment: Do you have any alternative suggestion to copy a single file into several folders named folder1, folder2, folder3 etc. ?