# Best way to execute 'ls' shell command with multiple arguments?

Tags: python, shell

I have the following command that I want to execute in Python and store in a variable:

```
ls -1 var1 2>/dev/null | grep var2 | grep var3 | head -n 1
```

But I can't get it to work. I tried using subprocess (both 'call' and 'check_output' as well as 'os.system' and nothing worked.. It always gave me an error or a wrong input, while when I execute this command in the shell it works properly.

Comment: BTW, this is in general very bad form, even in native shell -- as discussed in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs -- and doubly so in Python, where there are native tools for iterating over the directory tree. Not all possible filenames *can* be represented in a newline-delimited stream, so there necessarily exist names that `ls` will misrepresent.

Comment: If you want to call a bunch of shell commands, a shell script would be a more appropriate tool than a Python program. If you want to write Python, you should use tools like `os.listdir` and Python's own string matching utilities.

Comment: What Charles Duffy said. Also see the answers to [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/88378) on Unix & Linux.

Comment: thanks for that guys, i'll definitely keep it in mind.

Comment: If you're concerned about script portability you should _definitely_ avoid parsing the output of `ls`! There are many variations of `ls` out there in the wild, and even on the one machine its output can change depending on the settings of various environment variables.

Comment: Yes i agree, that is why i replied to treesloth's answer saying i won't end up using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For executing shell commands you'd use the subprocess module.

Usage and examples can be found at:
[Python Docs: subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

The actual python code for calling bash would look like this

```
import subprocess
task = subprocess.Popen("ls -1 var1 2>/dev/null | grep var2 | grep var3 | head -n 1",
                        shell=True, 
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
directory = task.stdout.read()
print(directory) # result
```

The recommended way though would to use python to do the directory search.
[Python listdir()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir)
The command for oslistdir could look like this

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if re.match(r'[0-9]+.*\.jpg', f)]
```

Comment: for this specific case i decided to use python's 'os' module for script portability sake, but your answer is great and will be useful in future tasks, thanks!

Comment: With Py3 you can simplify just by using `subprocess.check_output`, given the OP is using `head -n 1` it looks like they just want the first result, so just assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any problem when using `subprocess` :

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> sub = subprocess.Popen("ls -1 var1 2>/dev/null | grep var2 | grep var3 | head -n 1", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> str = sub.stdout.read()
>>> str
''
```

You can find additional informations regarding calling shell command while saving the output [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353054/call-a-shell-command-containing-a-pipe-from-python-and-capture-stdout).

Hope it'll be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure you are executing in a shell, as you are relying on the shell to dispatch the pipes, e.g. (Py>3.1):

```
import subprocess
var1, var2, var3 = "var1", "var2", "var3"
cmd = "ls -1 {} 2>/dev/null | grep {} | grep {} | head -n 1".format(var1, var2, var3)
result = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
```

Comment: This will not work as intended if any of `var1`, `var2`, or `var3` contain any whitespace or glob metacharacters.

Comment: Seems a strange thing to assume given the OP's original questions uses these vars

Comment: The original question uses literal strings; you changed them to Python variables.

Comment: True, assumption on my part they are intended to be substituted variables - defaulted vars to the literals...