# How to save cmd output to text file through another script python

Tags: python, system

I am able to save the cmd data onto a text file using the following command:

```
python code_3.py > output.txt
```

However I am calling code_3.py from primary_script.py by writing:

```
import code_3
os.system('loop3.py')
```

But I want it to perform the functionality of the what the previous line does. This doesn't work:

```
os.system('loop3.py > opt.txt ')
```

Can someone please tell me what to do?

Comment: You should probably be using the `subprocess` module, `os.system` is pretty much deprecated.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353054/running-a-command-line-containing-pipes-and-displaying-result-to-stdout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it with the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module:

```
import subprocess
import sys

p1 = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "loop3.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, err = p1.communicate()

with open('opt.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(output.decode())
```