# How to extract the output of a cmd query to a textfile using python

Tags: python, cmd, command-prompt, ping, python-3.8

I have this simple python code;

```
import os
os.system('cmd /k "ping google.com"')
```

After running the code, a cmd window is displayed with the following result;

```
Pinging google.com [216.58.223.238] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 216.58.223.238: bytes=32 time=57ms TTL=120
Reply from 216.58.223.238: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=120
Reply from 216.58.223.238: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=120
Reply from 216.58.223.238: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=120

Ping statistics for 216.58.223.238:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 9ms, Maximum = 57ms, Average = 26ms
```

How do I copy this code from the cmd window and save to a textfile using python?

Comment: Check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25023233/how-to-save-python-screen-output-to-a-text-file

Comment: It can't work, can't take output from cmd. but can work on simple code

Comment: You can do that on simple code but in a bigger one you should use the [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/a/47425461/9705687](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47425461/9705687)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest solution would be forwarding the output into a file.
`ping -n 20 {ip_addr} >output.txt`
(do ">>" to append and not overwrite)
In addition, you should use `subprocess.Popen()` instead of `os.system()` for good practice.
Then you can just open the text file as usual and perform the actions you want to make.\

**Edit**
If you are on the command line and execute `ls > output.txt`, the text you normally see in your terminal will be written to the file after the ">" operator. Doing `subprocess.Popen("ping -n 20 {} >> output.txt".format(ip),shell=True)` is essentially the same. (I used `>>` in this case, to not overwrite the file with the newest output every time, but to append the new content)

```
import subprocess 
with open ('ip-source.txt') as file:
      test = file.read()
      test = test.splitlines()
      for ip in test:
          subprocess.Popen('ping -n 20 {} >> ping_output.txt'.format(ip),shell=True)
```

I hope this is the solution you were looking for and I understood you right.
Regards, Lars

Comment: Not so understand. Can you give some example? Thank a lots!!

Comment: you have helped me solve the problem, thank a lots!!!

Comment: If so, I would appreciate if you marked the question as accepted so others know too.