# Python: replacing shell pipeline with an ssh connection

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, piping

I have the following nice bash command :

```
cat SomePythonScript.py | ssh remote_machine 'cat - | python'
```

that works very fine and that I want to write in Python. I tried with  'subprocess'  but did not get that far.  Can  someone help me ?

```
from subprocess import  PIPE , Popen

p1 = Popen(["cat ", "SomePythonScript.py"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["remote_machine"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p3 = Popen(["cat -", "python"], stdin=p2.stdout, stdout=PIPE)

p1.stdout.close()  
p2.stdout.close()  

output = p3.communicate()[0]
```

I tried also with 2 processes/ pipes

```
from  subprocess import PIPE , Popen  
p1 = Popen([["cat", "SomePythonScript.py"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["remote_machine","cat", "- python"], stdin=p1.stdout,    stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close() 
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

I would be very glad to any help, suggestion , advices, explanation  solution...  Thk in advance

Comment: `cat - | ...`? RLY?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [running a command line containing Pipes and displaying result to STDOUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353054/running-a-command-line-containing-pipes-and-displaying-result-to-stdout)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your use of `Popen`. The only things that's wrong is that you are missing the `ssh` command, and that you are trying to run three processes when there are only two in the bash command you're trying to mimic--`'cat - | python'` is just an argument to the `ssh` command.

The following should better mimic your bash command:

```
from subprocess import  PIPE , Popen

p1 = Popen(["cat", "SomePythonScript.py"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["ssh", "remote_machine", "cat - | python"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)

p1.stdout.close()  

output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's not worth replicating the [useless use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat) even if you want the rest of your pipeline.

Secondly, it's conspicuous that although you included the entirely pointless `cat` command, you *omitted* the only command that actually does something - neither attempt runs `ssh` at all.

---

EDIT For future reference - since the accepted answer is  *still* indulging in the same useless uses of cat, this is what the code ought to look like:

```
from subprocess import  PIPE , Popen

p = Popen(["ssh", "remote_machine", "python"], 
          stdin=open("SomePythonScript.py",'r'), stdout=PIPE)
output = p.communicate()[0]
```

And *this* is what the original shell code should have been in the first place:

```
< SomePythonScript.py ssh remote_machine python
```

Your original code contained

- ```
  p1 = Popen([["cat", "SomePythonScript.py"], stdout=PIPE)
  ```

  which has the same effect as `open("SomePythonScript.py",'r')`, but at the cost of running a child process for no benefit at all.
- ```
  p2 = Popen(["ssh", "remote_machine", "cat - | python"], ...
  ```

  which runs an additional redundant process on the remote machine. Since `cat -` is just copying its stdin to stdout, you can omit it completely

Comment: First thank  you ,     with the first point your are right.  The bash command works exactly the same without the  the second cat. On the second point I just delete the ssh command  by error as as I was changing the name of the remote machine.