# Python: Replacing shell pipeline with an ssh connection and get back result in a python variable

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

This question  refers to some extends to this post.
([Python: replacing shell pipeline with an ssh connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51424025/python-replacing-shell-pipeline-with-an-ssh-connection)). 
It was about translating in Python the following  bash command:

```
cat SomePythonScript.py | ssh remote_machine 'python'
```

with the subprocess library and  the following code :

```
 from subprocess import  PIPE , Popen

  p1 = Popen(["cat", "SomePythonScript.py"], stdout=PIPE)
  p2 = Popen(["ssh", "remote_machine", "cat - | python"], stdin=p1.stdout,stdout=PIPE)

  p1.stdout.close()  
  output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

its works good. Then I convert  the output in bytes  with :

```
output_= ast.literal_eval(output[0].decode("utf-8"))
```

to get back the data in my python project: It is  where  I am not happy and would need some help. 
**Now, I want to avoid the ast.literal_eval** and get directly the data.

I though  about changing the  bash command  to

```
var="$(cat ssh_get_data_QA_machine.py | ssh con-qa-1010 'python')
echo $var
```

and translate it with subprocess. Is it the right approach ?   If yes,  Could you help me with  the subprocess ? Since last week I make some progress with subprocess but once again I  am blocked :(  ahhh

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: You're absolutely wedded to your useless uses of cat, aren't you? It's just so... _unnecessary_.

Comment: So , please let me know how  you would do it without  cat ? I am open minded  and  would be glad to learn something new.

Comment: You mean like I explained in great detail in my answer to your other question?

Comment: I delete the 'cat' and change it   with an open(pythonfile.py,r) as you suggest  but I still have the same problem .  I have to use ***ast.literal_eval***  to get the data  back in python .   Can you explain it again  for a non advance programmer, because I don't get it

Comment: I guess my approach is  wrong with  subprocess.   According to the library I just found   :  "communicate() returns a tuple (stdout_data, stderr_data). The data will be strings if streams were opened in text mode; otherwise, bytes."